# How to add more then one names to a command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

If I add more then one property to "name" then it doesn't detect any.

This works:

```
module.exports = {
  name: "info",
  description: "Gives full details of a user.",
  async execute(...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But if i try to add something like "whois" to "name":

```
module.exports = {
  name: ["info", "whois"],
  description: "Gives full details of a user.",
  async execute(...) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then the command just stops working.

Here the code for my index.js:

```
const infoCommandModule = require(`./BotCommands/Info.js`);
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === `${infoCommandModule.name}`) {
  infoCommandModule.execute(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when it's an array you can't compare it to a string. You can use `Array#includes()` though that checks if a given string is included in the array:

```js
const infoCommandModule = require('./BotCommands/Info.js')

if (infoCommandModule.name.includes(msg.content.toLowerCase)) {
  infoCommandModule.execute(...)
}
```

Please note that you will need to use arrays for every `name` in your commands. If you want to accept arrays and strings too, you will need to check if `name` is an array. You can use `Array.isArray(name)` for that.